# Change default picture folder in new PowerPoint presentation to SharePoint library

Tags: office

A client has a SharePoint intranet where documents and pictures are a large part of the usage. I was given the following user story:

"A user goes to a Document Library on a site, chooses New Document from the ribbon, gets the dropdown of available templates, chooses the "xxxxx PowerPoint English" template and starts working on a new document. When they want to insert a picture in to that PowerPoint presentation they choose Insert, Picture and they get the dialogue where the default picture location is set to  [username]\My Pictures. This default folder should be a universal picture library that exists on the SharePoint intranet that has a lot of pictures specifically for presentations. This picture library has one URL, and every user has security access to read this folder."

My research found out that I can use run-> regedit -> HKEY_CURRENT_USER -> ... -> User Shell folders -> My pictures, open the value string, change it, and you are supposed to be good to go.

Although this was did not fix it when I tried it on my local DEV server, and I haven't heard of anyone who used this in co-operation with a SharePoint picture library. So I have no way of knowing if this is supposed to be working with a SharePoint URL instead of normal C:\User\My Pictures.

And for all those out there who don't like www.experts-exchange.com: I was able to get my answer there. [Link to unlocked solution for this question at Experts Exchange.](http://rdsrc.us/XQ2sfR)